# count semicolon separated values in all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe ('dftags') with 23 columns. I would like pandas to count the number of semicolon separated values in each column.

```
dftags.bp_tl.str.count(';').add(1)
```

gives me what I want, but only for one column ('bp_tl').

```
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      3.0
      ... 
923    NaN
924    NaN
925    NaN
926    2.0
927    NaN
Name: bp_tl, Length: 928, dtype: float64
```

How do I get the result for all columns?

EDIT

I found a better solution:

```
tagcount = dftags.stack().str.count(r'[^;\s][^\;]*[^;\s]*').unstack()
```

Comment: Use apply in this case: `dftags.apply(lambda x: x.str.count(";").add(1))`

Comment: Is it the count of commas or semicolons?

Answer (score 1):

Try that?

```
dftags.applymap(lambda x: str(x).count(';')).add(1)
```

Comment: It works, but there's a little issue: 'NaN' now appears as '1'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `applymap`, use `apply`. The code is:

```py
dftags.apply(lambda x: str(x).count(';')).add(1)
```